# SerializeArray on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parts order form with a review page before submitting. I want to display all input values so that the user can double check the form before submitting. The code below works on a button click but i want to do it on a keyup:

```
<form action="">
  Field1: <input type="text" name="test1" value="test1" class="displayvalues"><br>
  Field2: <input type="text" name="test2" value="test2" class="displayvalues"><br>
  Field3: <input type="text" name="test3" value="test3" class="displayvalues"><br>
</form>

 <div id="results"></div>

 <button>Serialize form values</button>
```

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".displayvalues").keyup(function(){
    var x = $("form").serializeArray();
    $.each(x, function(i, field){
        $("#results").append(field.name + ":" + field.value + " ");
         });
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```html
<form action="">
  Field1: <input type="text" name="test1" value="test1" class="displayvalues"><br>
  Field2: <input type="text" name="test2" value="test2" class="displayvalues"><br>
  Field3: <input type="text" name="test3" value="test3" class="displayvalues"><br>
</form>

 <div id="results"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".displayvalues").keyup(function(){
    $("#results").html('');
    $(".displayvalues").each(function(){
       $("#results").append(this.name + ":" + this.value + " ");
         });
     });
 });
 
 </script>
```